# Visual Studio Code User Individual Configuration for Project

Tags: visual-studio-code, configuration, task

I have a project created with defined tasks, for other users to use in my institution.

But now one of my tasks needs a parameter that should be a user defined directory.

How can each user have a configuration file in their project that my tasks can read and get the directory they want the out put to go?

This is a example of my task :

```
        {
        "label": "Generate File",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "cscript.exe",
        "args": [
            "//NoLogo",
            "${workspaceFolder}/scripts/build.vbs",
            "0",
            "${output}",
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
```

The output should be a folder define by each of the users in a configuration or setting file they can put in their project.

Edit :

As Requested i tried to do this

inside my .vscode folder i created a file named settings.json

with this as content

```
{
"env": {
    "dirLoc": "C:\\output\\"
    }
}
```

and tried to use this variable in my tasks.json file

```
        {
        "label": "Generate File",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "cscript.exe",
        "args": [
            "//NoLogo",
            "${workspaceFolder}/scripts/build.vbs",
            "0",
            "${env:dirLoc}",
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
```

but still i did not get anything in the value, it came blank

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable).

It has the command [`extension.commandvariable.file.content`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable#file-content) where you can read file content and use it in a variable in the task or launch.

The file can be plain text, key-value, json and yaml.

Comment: is there a way to do this without a extension?

Comment: @rread you can use an environment variable and the VSC `${env}` variable

Comment: @rread you have to use the shell/Terminal/OS environment